# Turn url /parts/ into parameters with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a Magento site for which I installed a module to paginate, sort and filter some category pages.

This will generate links such as
https://www.example.com/en/mycategory/where/dir/asc/order/price/

or
https://www.example.com/en/mycategory/where/limit/30/

I would like to redirect those (not just rewrite but an actual redirect for better SEO) to a page like the following
https://www.example.com/en/mycategory/p/4/
redirects to
https://www.example.com/en/mycategory?p=4

and 
https://www.example.com/en/mycategory/where/dir/asc/order/price/
to
https://www.example.com/en/mycategory?dir=asc&order=price

Since categories can have subcategories, a link can also have more subdivision before the "/where/" making htaccess even worse.
URL: https://example.com/en/mycategory/mysubcategory/where/p/5

I tried the following htaccess code, which is supposed to be recursive, but I get 500 internal server errrors.

## Turn the slashed URL into query strings

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/where/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ $1/where/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA, R=301]
```

## Remove the "/where/" from the url

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/where/?$ $1 [L,QSA, R=301]
```

(I'd prefer a 301 redirect because of SEO reasons, don't want my pagerank splitting up.)

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: 500Error is probably because of a space between **QSA,** and **R=301]**

Comment: *thuds head on desk*